# Wordpress 500 Internal server error when activating custom theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, internal-server-error

Whenever I try to activate my custom built theme on the clients server, the website returns a '500 - Internal Server Error'.

[image]

The theme is working fine on my local machine, MAMP on my mac. I dont even know where to begin to solve this problem!

As far as I am aware, the wordpress is a fresh install and I have no plugins that are activated.

Comment: You should consider asking this on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks, I will ask over there